# trigger after insert on table 1, insert on table 2 with where condition column from table 1

Tags: php, mysql

My trigger is not working at all.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER leave_credit_nt
AFTER INSERT ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO nonteaching_leavecredit (IdNum, Date_Hired, Emp_Stat, Date_Leave_Ac, Vac_Leave, Sick_Leave)
VALUES (new.IdNum, new.Date_Hired, new.Emp_Stat, new.Date_Hired + INTERVAL 1 YEAR, 0, 0)
WHERE employees.Emp_Type = 'NON-TEACHING';
END $$

DELIMITER
```

I want that the trigger will insert values into my second table only those with employees.emp_type = 'NON-TEACHING'. Can someone help me get this trigger working?

emp_type is a column in my table employees.

Answer (score 3):

Your [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) query is wrong. MySQL INSERT Syntax does not support the WHERE clause so your query as it stands will fail.

You cant use `WHERE` condition with `INSERT` query. If you are using `WHERE` condition, it means you already have that row in the table. So , you should use `UPDATE` query instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: recommending update.  It's not really known of/recommended here (that I've seen)

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional logic to your trigger with:

```
if new.Emp_Type = 'NON-TEACHING' then
    INSERT INTO nonteaching_leavecredit (IdNum, Date_Hired, Emp_Stat, Date_Leave_Ac, Vac_Leave, Sick_Leave)
    VALUES (new.IdNum, new.Date_Hired, new.Emp_Stat, new.Date_Hired + INTERVAL 1 YEAR, 0, 0);
end if;
```